# How to define mutually exclusive properties on a type in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the a class hierarchy like this:

```
export interface interfaceA {
  property1: string;
  property2: interfaceB;
}
    
export interface interfaceB{
  property3: interfaceC;
  property4: interfaceD;
}
    
export interface interfaceC{
  property5: string;
}
    
export interface interfaceD{
  property6: string;
}
```

I have to send data to an API, which will accept data where `interfaceB` have to contain only `interfaceC` when `interfaceD` is null and vice versa. Or it can contain both. **The API is out of our hand to change.**

**Here are some examples:**

When interfaceC is null (it needs to be the same way when interfaceD is null):

```
{
interfaceA :{
 property1: "somevalue",
 property2: {
  interfaceB:{
    property4: 
    {
      property6: "somevalue";
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

When both interfaceC and interfaceD both have values:

```
{
interfaceA :{
 property1: "somevalue",
 property2: {
  interfaceB:{
    property3: 
    {
      property5: "somevalue";
    },
    property4: 
    {
      property6: "somevalue";
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

How to create the JSON from TyepScript so that it can be sent to the API? I'm very new to TypeScript.

Comment: You just create your object normally as you would in JavaScript, and send it to the server as usual. Are you asking about how to create the _type_ for these objects?

Comment: when interfaceC is null , I am sending or creating the object , its json is becoming like interfaceC:null , which is not getting accepted in API ,

Comment: That is not how your JSON will look like, because `interfaceX` won't be visible in your data, since those are types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable [strictNullChecks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) in  your TS-Config so that `null` and `undefined` are not part of your types by default. (Consider activating all strict checks.)

Then you could define `interfaceB` like this:

```
export type interfaceB = {
  property3: interfaceC;
  property4: interfaceD;
} | {
  property3: interfaceC;
  property4: null; // you might try to remove this line
} | {
  property3: null; // you might try to remove this line
  property4: interfaceD;
};
```

This means that the data has to either contain `property3` or `property4` or both of them.